# display data in single field of a table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I am trying to display name and age in a single field of the table and I want data to be displayed in the place of `&nbsp;`. I tried the code below but it doesn't work.

CODE:

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","dva");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
       echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM apform");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "My Mood: ";
        echo $row['mood'];
        echo "<br>";
    }
?>

<thead>
    <tr>    
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Doctor</th>
        <th>Telephone</th>
        <th>Mobile</th>
        <th>Meeting Time</th>
        <th>Fee</th>
        <th>Date</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td data-title="Name"><span> <?php echo $row['name']; ?> </span></td>
        <td data-title="Relationship"><span>&nbsp;</span></td>
        <td data-title="Address"><span>&nbsp;</span></td>
        <td data-title="Telephone"><span>&nbsp;</span></td>
        <td data-title="Mobile"><span>&nbsp;</span></td>
        <td data-title="Contact at night"><span>&nbsp;</span></td>
        <td data-title="Next of kin"><span>&nbsp;</span></td>
        <td data-title="Delete"><span>&nbsp;</span></td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Write the `tbody` code inside `while` loop

Comment: Your code is proper ,what is not working?

Comment: Please learn basics of PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily achieve what you need to putting the while loop inside of your table and echoing out all of the relevant fields.

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","dva");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
       echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM apform");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "My Mood: ";
        echo $row['mood'];
        echo "<br>";
    }
?>

<thead>
    <tr>    
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Doctor</th>
        <th>Telephone</th>
        <th>Mobile</th>
        <th>Meeting Time</th>
        <th>Fee</th>
        <th>Date</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td data-title="Name"><span><?php echo $row['name']; ?></span></td>
        <td data-title="Relationship"><span><?php echo $row['relationship']; ?></span></td>
        <td data-title="Address"><span><?php echo $row['address']; ?></span></td>
        <td data-title="Telephone"><span><?php echo $row['telephone']; ?></span></td>
        <td data-title="Mobile"><span><?php echo $row['mobile']; ?></span></td>
        <td data-title="Contact at night"><span><?php echo $row['contact']; ?></span></td>
        <td data-title="Next of kin"><span><?php echo $row['nok']; ?></span></td>
        <td data-title="Delete"><span><a href="delete/<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Delete</a></span></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</tbody>
```

Comment: OP is not even caring about Checking the answer.@Pooshonk, what do u think?